# Github readme.md align images

Tags: html, css, github, markdown

I wish the two images on the readme file were vertically aligned, but I don't understand why on Github it is not succeeding.

How can I do it through markup languages?

Result:

[image]

```html
<div align="center">
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <img src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=anuraghazra&layout=compact&show_icons=true&title_color=ffffff&icon_color=34abeb&text_color=daf7dc&bg_color=151515" style="vertical-align: top;" />
    <img src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=anuraghazra&show_icons=true&title_color=ffffff&icon_color=34abeb&text_color=daf7dc&bg_color=151515" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1.** You can use a **table** (it has borders on github):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><img src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=anuraghazra&layout=compact&show_icons=true&title_color=ffffff&icon_color=34abeb&text_color=daf7dc&bg_color=151515"/></td>
    <td valign="top"><img src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=anuraghazra&show_icons=true&title_color=ffffff&icon_color=34abeb&text_color=daf7dc&bg_color=151515"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**2.** You can add **`align=top`** to the `img` tag:

***Note**: It works as intended on github but not in the snippet*

```html
<div>
    <img align=top src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=anuraghazra&layout=compact&show_icons=true&title_color=ffffff&icon_color=34abeb&text_color=daf7dc&bg_color=151515"/>
    <img align=top src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=anuraghazra&show_icons=true&title_color=ffffff&icon_color=34abeb&text_color=daf7dc&bg_color=151515"/>
<div>
```

Comment: I don't want them one on top of the other, but next to each other with the smaller image in height starting from the same height position as the other.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you want at first. I've edited my answer, see if it works for you. @Paul

Comment: It seems to work.
The problem being a table remains the edge, I tried everything, but the inline css also does not work for security reasons on the part of github.
I am looking for a solution.

Comment: I added another solution. I tested it on github and it works fine. Check it out @Paul

Comment: since I'm changing some things, I have to change the position of the objects again can I ask you for advice?

Comment: Sure. I'm not a CSS/html expert, but I'll try my best to help you. @Paul

Answer (score 0):

You should also add flex-direction:column to the flex div.
div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;"

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this by adding `height="200"` attribute in the `img` tag.

But it has a caveat though. GitHub won't let you remove the table border.

```
<table cellpadding="0">
  <tr style="padding: 0">
    <!-- GitHub Stats Card -->  
    <td valign="top"><img height="200" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=snsakib&count_private=true&show_icons=true&theme=tokyonight&hide_border=true&custom_title=My%20GitHub%20Stats"/></td>
    <!-- GitHub Top Language Card -->
    <td valign="top"><img height="200" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=snsakib&langs_count=6&layout=compact&theme=tokyonight&hide_border=true&hide=HTML&custom_title=Top%20Languages"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -4):

Let flexbox do the work for you. No need for the alignment on the images themselves; use `align-items: flex-start` on the container to align  both images to the top.

```html
<div align="center">
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: flex-start;">
    <img src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=anuraghazra&layout=compact&show_icons=true&title_color=ffffff&icon_color=34abeb&text_color=daf7dc&bg_color=151515"/>
    <img src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=anuraghazra&show_icons=true&title_color=ffffff&icon_color=34abeb&text_color=daf7dc&bg_color=151515" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works here, whereas your example above doesn't. Hard to say more without seeing a non-working example using my code.

Comment: You can find it in the link above example online, I did just as you indicated.